# Find the sum of all square submatrices of a given value in a matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I have to find all the submatrices in a matrix, then find their sum. But something seems to be going wrong in my code since the matrix generated with suposedly all the submatrices sum is not complete. Example: when i generate a matrix 6X8, submatrices 3X3 should be at least 6 at the first row, but only 4 are shown. This is my code:

```
    private void makeSubsquare() {
    int m,ver,sum=0,p,start;
    int n=r1;
    if(k>n)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=n-k;i++)
        {
            m=i; start=0; p=0; ver=0; sum=0; int j=0;
            while(j<n)
            {
                sum = sum + a[m][j];
                j++;
                p++;
                if(p==k)
                {   m++;
                    p=0;
                    ver++;
                    j=start;        
                }
                if((ver==k)&&(j<n))
                {
                    p=0;
                    m=i;
                    start++;
                    ver=0;
                    j=start;

                    System.out.print(sum + " ");
                    sum = 0;        
                }       
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do r1 and k get their values?

Comment: they get their values from console. r1 defines the row length and k defines the submatrix like a k=3, generates all the submatrices 3x3 inside the matrix

Comment: The result is short a column of submatrices! :/

Comment: I am unable to understand the problem statement here. What do you mean by a matrix and a submatrix? Can you give an example?

Comment: I managed to solve it. Apparently I was using the row variable to print the column that´s why it showed shorter in the console. However thank you so much!

Comment: Cool. Glad you were able to solve it.